# Will __bridge_transfer retain the original object?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

There is an example:

```
{
    CFMutableStringRef str = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 1000, CFSTR("Hello World") );
    NSString *value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)str ;
    NSLog(@"%@", value) ;
    CFRelease(str) ; // crash here
}
```

I know I should not release the str because the owner relationship transferred to `value`, but in the WWDC 2013 video `Fixing Memory Issues`, there is a picture, it seems to say when use `__bridge_transfer`, it will increase retain count of the original object by 1, I'm confused, Can anyone help?  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `__bridge_transfer` you're transferring ownership from CoreFoundation to ARC. This is also equivalent to calling `CFBridgingRelease(str)`. This essentially moves the object from CoreFoundation to the world of ARC where it will be ARC's responsibility to release the object. As a result, you will not, and must NOT call `CFRelease()` on your `CFMutableStringRef`.

However, you can also use `__bridge` (without the transfer) which will not touch ownership of the object. In this case, you will be responsible for releasing it using `CFRelease()`;

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `This essentially releases the object on the CoreFoundation side and retains it via ARC` this line is important, can you show me the reference ?

Comment: I may have added some confusion here. The CoreFoundation object isn't actually being released. The call to `CFBridgingRelease()` simply mimics a release call because now ARC will be responsible for calling release on the object. I've edited my answer to avoid confusion.

Here is the reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html

Comment: All right but can you explain `CF+1->ARC-managed'id':__bridge_transfer T` in the picture ?